# bind field value within period

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a modelView that contains an `Object`, similar to this

```
public class ExampleModelView
{
    public T object { get; set; }

    public ExampleModelView()
    {
        //...                
    }
}
```

To get that in my view I use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.object.attribute1)
```

So the above line returns a html with a **period**, which is giving me problems, like this

```
<input class="form-control" 
  id="object_attribute1" 
  name="object.attribute1" 
  type="text" value="..." 
  aria-required="true" 
  aria-invalid="false">
```

When I submit the form I'm not being able to bind the field value like this

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar([Bind(Include = "attribute1")] ExampleModelView t)
{
   //...
}
```

or those other ways

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar(ExampleModelView t)
{
   //...
}

 public ActionResult Cadastrar([Bind(Prefix= "object.attribute1")] ExampleModelView t)
 {
    //...
 }
```

So, if I change `TextBoxFor` to `TextBox` I can bind the object, but not my whole modelView.

What should I do in this case?

**EDIT**

Changed above `LabelFor` to `TextBoxFor`.

**Question**

How do I bind the attributes with the period?

Comment: Its not a problem at all - its supposed to include a period (and binding would not work without it). But `LabelFor()` does not generate a `<input>` so I assume you mean `TextBoxFor()`

Comment: That's true, I changed LabelFor fields for TextBoxFor. And I know generating with the period is not the problem, sorry, I may expressed myself wrongly. Updated that line as well.

Comment: But it does bind correctly (assuming `attribute1` is a property and not a field, and you use the 2nd example). Its not clear what you problem is.